# Programmatically triggering unwind segue

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, unwind-segue

I am making an app that segues to another screen on a "Go" button pressed. After 3 seconds, the screen turns black. Then 6 seconds later I want it to unwind back to the main screen without having to click a button, but so far I don't know how to get this to work.

I've ctrl dragged from the view controller to the exit button to create the unwind segue, but I don't know how to call it in code.

Here's the code I have in my GameViewController related to the segue:

import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let skView = view as! SKView
    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)

    //skView.showsFPS = true
    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    scene.vc = self
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}

@IBAction func unwindToMainMenu(sender: UIStoryboardSegue)
{

    //let gameVeiwController = sender.source]
    // Pull any data from the view controller which initiated the unwind segue.
}
```

Now here is my GameScene class, containing the function which I want to unwind the segue:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var vc: UIViewController?

private var circleNode : SKShapeNode?

var fingersDown: Int = 0
let maxFingers: Int = 4
var selectionStarted = false

var touchNodes = [UITouch:SKShapeNode]()

func startSelectionGame(){
    selectionStarted = true
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { timer in
        //both dont work
        self.vc!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMainMenu", sender: self.vc)
        self.vc?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMainMenu", sender: self)
    }
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: false) { timer in
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        self.changeColors()
    }

}
```

The Main.storyboard just has a segue from the first screen to the game screen.

I just want to get my program working, I know I'm missing something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do 3 things:

1. Find your segue in the *Document Outline* view on the left.  Click on it.
2. In the *Attributes Inspector* on the right, set the **Identifier** to `unwindToMainMenu`.
3. Call `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMainMenu", sender: self)` when you want to trigger it.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but now it is giving me this error: Value of type 'GameScene' has no member 'performSegue'

Comment: performSegue is a method on UIViewController, not on SKScene.

Comment: `performSegue` needs to be called on the `UIViewController`.  Try adding a property to your GameScene (`var vc: UIViewController?`) which will hold the viewController and set it after you create the GameScene.  Then use it to call `vc?.performSegue...`

Comment: So I did that, and there are no errors. But when it should be going back to the main screen it doesn't do anything. This is my code: [self.vc!.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMainMenu", sender: self.vc)] & [self.vc?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToMainMenu", sender: self)] both don't work

Comment: Did you assign the `vc` property `scene.vc = self` before the `presentScene` call?

Comment: Yes, I do that in the viewDidLoad() of GameViewController

Comment: So do you have two GameViewControllers each presenting its own scene?  How are you performing the segue?

Comment: No I don't think so. I just updated my code to show more

Comment: This function `@IBAction func unwindToMainMenu(sender: UIStoryboardSegue)` should be defined in your first `ViewController`, not your `GameViewController`.  It it defined in the `ViewController` that you are unwinding to.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an unwind segue you could use:

```
dismiss(animated: true)
```